# collision error self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

This code starts printing "collision" before it hits the sprite.

This defines the "bullet"

```
class Magic(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Magic.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, spritegroup)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)
```

This is the collision detection code

```
            if magic.is_collided_with(enemy1):
                print("collision")
                enemy1.kill()
```

This defines the enemy

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Enemy1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, spritegroup)


    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

enemy1 is the enemy defined below
 `enemy1 =  Enemy(1400, 50)`

Comment: Can you define the situation of 'before it hits the sprite'? is it short before, or is it a little while before? It might also be related with how the collision inside the sprite works.

Comment: On which line is your error? What is the traceback? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: When using Sprites, you should always store the position in the rect attribute instead (or in addition, depends) of custom x/y attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The *Surface* is placed at a position on the display with the `blit` function.

You've to set the location of the rectangle, by an assignment to a virtual attribute (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)), e.g:

```py
class Magic(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        sprite.rec.topleft = sprite.x, sprite.y
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)
```

---

However, I recommend removing the `x` and `y` attributes. Use `rect.x` and `rect.y` instead. Set the location of the rectangle, either by a keyword argument:

```py
class Magic(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Magic.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, spritegroup)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)
```

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Enemy1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, spritegroup)

    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```